# Java's Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK returns incorrect value

Tags: java, calendar

Today is Monday (should return 2), but returns 7 (Saturday). What am I missing?

```
int today = Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK;
System.out.println(today);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of

```
int today = Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK;
```

you have to use

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int today = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

to get the value.

With your way you only print the value of the constant `Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK` and don't get the actual value for the day of your `Calendar` object.

Comment: +1. I wonder why the contract of the method is to accept `int` rather than accept a value from an enum.

Comment: ah, that was it - forgot the cal.get part! Thanks!

Comment: @kocko the Calendar class is from JDK 1.1 - there were no enum types at that time and the type-safe enum pattern was not widely spread. Please note that Java SE 8 introduced the new java.time package.

Comment: @Puce, thank you. Good to know that! I actually suspected something like this, but didn't check it. :)

Answer (score 1):

When you use

```
int today = Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK;
```

This is what is returned to you...

```
   /**
     * Field number for <code>get</code> and <code>set</code> indicating the day
     * of the week.  This field takes values <code>SUNDAY</code>,
     * <code>MONDAY</code>, <code>TUESDAY</code>, <code>WEDNESDAY</code>,
     * <code>THURSDAY</code>, <code>FRIDAY</code>, and <code>SATURDAY</code>.
     *
     * @see #SUNDAY
     * @see #MONDAY
     * @see #TUESDAY
     * @see #WEDNESDAY
     * @see #THURSDAY
     * @see #FRIDAY
     * @see #SATURDAY
     */
    public final static int DAY_OF_WEEK = 7;
```

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

The legacy date-time API (`java.util` date-time types and their formatting type, `SimpleDateFormat`) is outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using it completely and switch to `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using the modern API:**

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.TextStyle;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // To use JVM's timezone, simply remove the argument or use
        // ZoneId.systemDefault() as the argument
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));

        // As enum
        DayOfWeek dw = date.getDayOfWeek();
        System.out.println(dw); // Value
        System.out.println(dw.ordinal()); // Ordinal

        // As String
        String dayName = dw.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(dayName);

        // As int
        int day = dw.getValue();
        System.out.println(day);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
SATURDAY
5
Saturday
6
```

Learn more about the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Using `Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK` will return the field number (in that case 7) used for the `get` method.